# c memory leak problem

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc, free

i have c function in my project which creates a struct and returns the pointer.

```
typedef struct object 
{
 float var1; 
 float var2; 
} 
Object; 

Object *createObject(float newVar1, float newVar2) 
{
 Object *object; //create new structure 
 object = (Object*)malloc(sizeof(Object)); //malloc size for struct object
 if(object != NULL) //is memory is malloc'd
 {
  object->var1 = newVar1; //set the data for var1
  object->var2 = newVar2; //set the data for var2
  return object; //return the pointer to the struct
 }
 return NULL; //if malloc fails, return NULL
}
```

now the struct gets used and after a while i want to delete this structure, i made this function:

```
void deleteMarnix(Object *objectPointer)
{
 free(objectPointer); //free the memory the pointer is pointing to
 objectPointer = NULL; //stop it from becomming a dangling pointer
}
```

this last code snippet shows how i make an object, use it and try to delete it, however, it seems that it doesn't completely free the memory. what am i doing wrong?

```
Object *object = createObject(21.0f, 1.87f);
//do things here with object.
deleteMarnix(object);
```

Comment: You need to show how you know it's leaking, you could just be seeing pre-allocation by the CRT.

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems that it doesn't completely free the memory"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What free() does is not free the memory held by the pointer completely, but actually makes it available for later use if we call a malloc after calling free().

An evidence to this is you will be able to access the memory location after calling free and before setting the pointer to NULL ( assuming  you haven't already called malloc() ). Of course the values will be reset to some default values. ( On some compilers i found int was set to 0 ).

Although there is no memory leak, this might answer your question.

Let us know :)

Answer (score 3):

From the snippets you posted, there's no leak.

I think that with:

> it seems that it doesn't completely free the memory

you mean that  `object` still holds the old value.

---

In `deleteMarnix`, when you set `objectPointer` to `NULL`, you only set the value of the pointer in that function scope.

It doesn't set the value of the actual pointer `object` in the outer function.

To do that you can either:

1. set it to `NULL` in the outer function

   ```
   Object *object = createObject(21.0f, 1.87f);
   deleteMarnix( object );
   object = NULL;
   ```
2. pass a pointer to a pointer to your `deleteMarnix` function:

   ```
   void deleteMarnix(Object **objectPointer)
   {
     free(*objectPointer); //free the memory the pointer is pointing to
     *objectPointer = NULL; //stop it from becomming a dangling pointer
   }
   ...
   Object *object = createObject(21.0f, 1.87f);
   deleteMarnix( &object );
   ```

Comment: It should still be freed() and not leak.

Comment: Correct. It's only the copy of pointer in your last scope which remains as a "dangling pointer", but no memory leak occurs. I also recommend declaring `deleteMarnix` as receiving an `Object **`.

Comment: Of course, but it is getting free'd. I think that by "it seems that it doesn't completely free the memory", OP is meaning that `object` still holds the old value.